# How to take value in a variable from array output in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a output like below using print_r
now i want to save a particular value in a variable for later use. below is the output in array format.

```
Array 
 (
[count] => 1 [0] => 
Array ( [objectclass] => 
Array ( [count] => 4 [0] => top [1] => person [2] => organizationalPerson 
[3] => user ) 
[0] => objectclass [cn] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => Tomas Alva ) 
[1] => cn [title] => Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => Assistant Director )
)
)
```

i want to get the value "Tomas Alva" and "Assistant Director" in two variables.

How can i get this.

Comment: your array is impossible because indexes are same there. whcih is not possible in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You can take it like this `$variable[0]['cn'][0]`. But this is not quite correct for later usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working for Name that is "Tomas Alva". Please let me know the format for Position also that is "Assistant Director"

Comment: For Asistant Director -> `$variable[0]['title'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = Array 
    (
        [count] => 1 [0] => 
            Array ( 
                [objectclass] => Array ( 
                        [count] => 4 
                        [0] => top 
                        [1] => person 
                        [2] =>  organizationalPerson 
                        [3] => user 
                ) 
                [0] => objectclass 
                [cn] => Array ( 
                    [count] => 1 
                    [0] => Tomas Alva 
                ) 
                [1] => cn 
                [title] => Array ( 
                    [count] => 1 
                    [0] => Assistant Director 
                )
          )
   );

$name = $arr['count']['cn']['0'];
$position = $arr['count']['title']['0'];
```

BTW, your array is *weird*. Why mixing counted indices amongst named ones ??? `count, 0, 1, ...`